# Failed to list lazy routes: Unknown module AppModule after Angular update

Tags: angular

I'm not specifing lazy routing on app.module anywhere, but it throws me this error and fails to compile:

```
ERROR in Failed to list lazy routes: Unknown module '/Users/heikopiirme/Documents/realNewClient/client/src/app/app.module#AppModule'.
```

The only place I'm using lay loading is here:

```
{
    path: 'logistics',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/logistics/logistics.module').then(m => m.LogisticsModule),
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard, NgxPermissionsGuard ],
    data: {
      permissions: {
        only: [Role.logistics_manager],
        redirectTo: '/home'
      }
    }
  }
```

This gave me an error but after switching to the new syntax it's fixed. How am I supposed to fix this for AppModule?

Answer (score 5):

I got this error after upgrading my learning project to 8 
Like op, I was surprised to get this as I am not using lazy loading.

My issue was that one of the IMPORT statements was wrong. 
I finally happened to notice that.

```
import { HeroesComponent } from './Heroes/heroes1/heroes.component';
   and the error shows up

enableProdMode();

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent },
```

If i correct the path to be (take out the 1 in the folder,heroes1--> heroes)

```
./Heroes/heroes/heroes.component
```

The error disappears and the app compiles.

This is a crazy red herring. 
Migrating to 8 from 7 has been rough for a variety of reasons. 
Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a bad import statement. Using the --prod argument showed the additional errors more clearly: ng build --prod

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the `import(...)`, its much simpler:

```
...
path: 'logistics', loadChildren: './views/logistics/logistics.module#LogisticsModule'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was caused by importing CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA from the wrong place. Apparently there's one in @angular/compiler and @angular/core. @angular/core is the correct one. I found the error by turning aot on temporarily. My app can't support aot at the moment but it puts out more errors when you turn it on. I got some cryptic error about NgModule.schemas needing to be an array of schemas. I eventually removed my existing import and looked at all the options for auto import.

This seems to be an error people are getting for a variety of unrelated reasons. Good luck to everyone who finds themselves on this page.

Answer (score 0):

For me, as with most thing node, I just needed to wipe node_modules and run `npm install` again.